# Map or flattenMap in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm new to ReactiveCocoa. How do I know when should I use map: or flattenMap: ? And How do I know whether it is a *stream-of-streams* or a regular stream? Here I got some code which I can't understand:

```
- (RACSignal *)signInSignal {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [self.signInService signInWithUsername:self.usernameTextField.text
                                      password:self.passwordTextField.text
                                      complete:^(BOOL success) {
                                          [subscriber sendNext:@(success)];
                                          [subscriber sendCompleted];
                                      }];
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

This method return a stream-of-streams. But why? Can anyone explain it for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `map` operator when you want to intercept whenever a Signal sends a value and have the opportunity to alter that value or send a completely different value. A way to think about this is a production line that passes partially completed products down the line. There are various points on the production line where a line operator will pick the product and screw something in or alter it in some way.

`Flatten map` is for when you might want to inject another Signal into some other signal that depends on the initial signal. You can therefor use the initial signal to effect or determine the signal returned. This is one of the ways you can take one or more signals and join them in a way that results in one signal. Hence the terminology: flatten. The other slightly different ways you can do this in RAC is `merge:` and `switchToLatest()` to name a few. Imaging you had a signal that did a network fetch based on a particular search query. Then imagine you had another signal for text typed into a search box. In order to do a search request based on the current search query in the searchText signal you could use a flatten map.

```
self.searchTextSignal.flattenMap({(object: AnyObject!) -> RACSignal! in
    if let searchQuery: String = object as? String {
        return self.networkFetchSignal(query: searchQuery)
    }
    return RACSignal.empty()
}).subscribeNext({(object: AnyObject) -> Void in 
   //the results
})
```

Comment: So can I comprehend it like this... Since you typed some text into a search box, here it sends a signal (Signal 1). Then you should did some searching operation in flattenMap, here it sends another signal (Signal 2). Signal 2 is included in Signal 1, and we should use flattenMap: instead map: . Right?

Comment: Hmm. Kind of. So basically I want to use both the searchTextSignal and the the networkFetchSignal. However the `networkFetchSignal` depends on the `searchTextSignal` for its search query. So I wanted to "flatten" the `searchTextSignal` into the `networkFetchSignal`. So i take the text that is sent by the `searchTextSignal` and pass it into the `networkFetchSignal` which is a method that performs a network call and returns the results as next events. It is this signal not the `searchTextSignal` that is utlimately subscribed to.

Answer (score 1):

For the map or flattenMap question, I would like to quote the comment from this:
https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/448#issuecomment-34977600

Comment: Please quote the relevant text in your answer. Link-only answers are discouraged because the content might change or disappear.

Comment: Cool also that documentation would be hidden in issue comments.

Comment: Also that comment is pretty unhelpful to somebody new to this stuff.